# Using Responsive Screens in Angular using bootstrap with multiple instances of the same component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, initialization, components

I am coding a responsive screen using bootstrap grid system (xs, sm, and md and up). The code below works as far as displaying the app-prize-list only once, depending on the screen size. However, the app-prize-list component is being initialized 3 times, once for each occurrence in the code, regardless of whether they will be shown based on the grid system.

I can tell because the initialization hits the back end (database) and I can see the calls made are multiples of the components on the page. If I comment out one of the instances of app-prize-list then I see only two hits to the database. If I comment out two of them, then I see only one hit to the database. If don't comment out any of them then I see three hits to the database.

I would expect the section that is not being displayed based on the screen size to be completely ignored. Is there another way to ensure that the right section (based on screen size) is displayed and that only the components that apply to that section are activated?

Comment: <div class="d-block d-sm-none">

    <app-prize-list [tD]="tD" [tD_Counter]="tD_Counter" [listType]="eListType.Vertical"></app-prize-list>

</div>

Comment: <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">

    <app-prize-list [tD]="tD" [tD_Counter]="tD_Counter" [listType]="eListType.Vertical"></app-prize-list>

</div>

Comment: <div class="d-none d-md-block">

    <app-prize-list [tD]="tD" [tD_Counter]="tD_Counter" [listType]="eListType.Vertical" [maxPositions]="0" instanceName="list2"></app-prize-list>

</div>

Comment: Sorry to add the code like that, as comments. Something didn't go as planned when the question was created.

Answer (score 0):

You using app-prize-list component 3 times so angular is initialising it 3 times , display:none is related to css and the way its presented on the screen but the component is getting created irrespective of anything.

You can create component dynamically to solve this issue.
You can refer documentation of creating dynamic components in angular on their site 
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

A workaround would be to use media queries and define your custom css

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
  .d-custom{
    color:red;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .d-custom{
    color:blue;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  .d-custom{
    color:green;
  }
 }

@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  .d-custom{
    color: yellow;
  }
 }
```

Comment: That makes sense. I will try the solution suggested and will provide an update. Thanks so much for the prompt answer.